# How can I edit text in "column mode"?

Tags: windows, sublimetext3

How can I select multiple columns in Sublime Text?

What I mean by that, is the ability to select blocks of text, on the selected columns. In [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) you can achieve this by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + drag on Windows.

Here is a live example: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html

Comment: i found this with google
http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/column_selection.html :)

Comment: For some reason, a search engine pointed to here for the same for [Komodo Edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_Edit)/[Komodo IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_IDE). For Komodo, it is Shift + Alt + arrow keys to make a column/block selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See *[Column Selection](http://sublimetext.com/docs/3/column_selection.html)*.

For Windows, it's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right click.

Comment: Edit: Damn it, also found it but confused the right mouse button with the left.

Comment: You can also use CTRL+ALT + (UP|DOWN|LEFT|RIGHT)